# The smallest `max_arity` of compound terms in ISO Prolog programs

Tags: prolog, portability, data-representation, iso-prolog

Prolog systems aiming at [iso-prolog](/questions/tagged/iso-prolog) conformity do *not* have to support compound terms with *arbitrarily large* arities. The Prolog flag `max_arity` reflects this.

According to ISO/IEC 13211-1:1995:

> 7.11.2.3   Flag: max_arity
>
> Possible values: The default value only
>
> Default value: implementation defined
>
> Changeable: No
>
> Description: The maximum arity allowed for any compound term, or `unbounded` when the processor has no limit for the number of arguments for a compound term.

So Prolog systems *may or may not* impose an **upper** limit on `max_arity` ... but what about the **lower** limit?  Is, say, `5` okay?

**NO!**
[ISO/IEC 13211-1:1995/Cor.2:2012](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/iso-prolog/info), Technical Corrigendum 2, defines `call/2..8` as:

> 8.15.4 call/2..8 
>  *...* 
> NOTE — **A standard-conforming processor may implement call/N in one of the following ways** because error condition d is implementation dependent (3.91).

1. Implement only the seven built-in predicates call/2 up to call/8.
2. Implement call/2..N up to any N that is within 8..max_arity (7.11.2.3). Produce existence errors for larger arities below max_arity.
3. Implement call/9 and above only for certain execution modes.

All of these ways *only* imply `Max_arity >= 8`—but nothing more.

So my question has (at least) *two sides*:

1. **Prolog User**: 
   "What is the maximum arity I *may use* if I want to avoid vendor lock-in?"
2. **Prolog Implementor**: 
   "What is the smallest `Max_arity` I *must support* if I aim<sup>1</sup> at ISO-Prolog conformity?"

Right now, I'm *quite* sure the answer is this:

> Yes, `Max_arity = 8` is okay.

But is it in fact so? Are there clues I am missing?

---

<sup>**Footnotes:** 
 1) I do.</sup>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a gap somehow. max_arity only covers the compound size. But there is no flag for predicate size. The two things might vary as SWI-Prolog shows. But SWI-Prolog names the limit wrongly max_arity, although its not its max_arity flag:

```
/* SWI-Prolog 8.3.19 */

?- functor(_,f,10000).
true.

?- functor(F,f,10000), assertz(F).
ERROR: Cannot represent due to `max_arity' (limit is 1024, request = 10000)

?- current_prolog_flag(max_arity, X).
X = unbounded.
```

The predicate size limit might be more relevant to call/n than the compound size. The ISO core standard definition is a little unsatisfactory.

But its not thoroughly checked, but a fix on SWI-Prologs side is underway:

```
?- functor(F,f,10000), assertz(test:-F).
F = f(_ ...)

?- functor(F,f,10000), call(F,a).
%%% crash
```

**Edit 25.02.2021:**
The glitch in the error message is only explained when you look at the C-Code of SWI-Prolog, which has a C Constant MAXARITY with the meaning of predicate size. This Constant and the Error Message possibly predates the ISO core standard, which introduced another constant.

Answer (score 3):

Ad 2: Standard conformity is a precondition for a working system. It is by no means a guarantee that a system is fit for any purpose including the one you are (reasonably) interested in. Given that, I'd say 1 is the minimum, as zero cannot be the arity of a compound term. Of course, any attempt to produce a list would produce a representation error. It could be worse, see Purpose of [this](/a/25125542/772868).

The usage of built-ins with higher arity (5 or 8) is not precluded in such a processor. After all, a conforming processor needs just to prepare Prolog text for execution (5.1.a) and correctly execute Prolog goals (5.1.b). Nowhere is it stated that such goals are represented as compound terms.

But of course that is what we expect, as we expect to be able to program our own top level loop which is itself out of scope of ISO/IEC 13211-1.

Ad 1: As for future portability, 255 appears to be the minimum. But IF has 127. Minerva 125. Of course `unbounded` would be the best choice, with up to 7 for fast and compact representation.

> Are there clues I am missing?

The relation of compound terms to predicates is often overseen in this context.  A system may support predicates with only a smaller arity than `max_arity` — the appropriate error to issue here would be a `resource_error`. Compare this situation to a system with `current_prolog_flag(max_arity, unbounded)` and the goal `functor(F,f,N)` with `N` exceeding the processor's address space (in current implementations). While such a goal would never succeed in current implementations, it still issues a `resource_error` and not a `representation_error`.

Comment: Alright! But I'm still chewing on the answer you linked to

Comment: I think I get the "ad 1" part of your answer, but I have to admit I am not perfectly happy with it. Maybe there is no single perfect answer. If an implementor chooses "unbounded", the users of that particular system are somewhat encouraged to write code that does not run on the systems with some finite max_arity value. Consider SICStus and SWI. SICStus may or may not switch from 255 to unbounded, but, for the time being, SWI programs that effectively use a value larger than 255 cannot run directly with SICStus. This problem gets compounded with systems that are no longer in active development.

Comment: My program manager boiled the decision process down to "in cases of uncertainty, whenever possible, do / imitate / fake whatever the competition does". Smart.

Comment: @repeat: who is your competition? The past or the future?

Comment: Good question! My PM suggested I deal with the issue on a going forward basis.

Answer (score 0):

The ISO Prolog standard predicate with the larger number of arguments is `sub_atom/5`. We can use this predicate to justify at least `call/6` and thus a maximum arity of at least 6:

```
| ?- call(sub_atom, A, B, C, D, E).
```

Of course, with `call/6`, nothing prevents the programmer to call e.g.

```
| ?- call(foo(A,B,C), D, E, F, G, H)
```

Comment: `call/8` is largest see OP